# How to compute entry price of perpetual swap contracts in Bitmex, specific example

Tags: price

I am trying to understand how the entry price is computed. I though it was just a weighted average (that is, SUM(amount * price) / SUM(amount)) and this does match the example at their documentation:

https://bitmex.freshdesk.com/en/support/solutions/articles/13000081236-how-to-calculate-entry-price

However, I am testing with a test account, and the entry price reported does not match. This is the status of my test account. I have only made these trades:

https://i.imgur.com/4a23jBp.png

And here is the same in a Google Spreedsheet, so that is easier to interact with. I had added my method to compute the entry price, which reports 47983,92857; different from the entry price reported at Bitmex of 47976.1271:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12hpngiwMUda386r86WiTKGNPgVCbl-Gnx9lbs_FvI3k/edit?usp=sharing

Can anyone help me undersand how to compute the entry price reported by Bitmex?